# How to add a Bridging Header in XCode 6 (final release)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm having some problems adding a **bridging header** file to my project. It has been always generated automatically by **XCode** when importing my Obj-C libraries...but now, with the final release of **XCode 6** this doesn't happen anymore...do you know why?

Thank you so much
Cheers! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you have to do:

- Select your project in the project navigator.
- Navigate to **Build Settings**.
- Search for `Objective-C Bridging Header`.
- Set the value of **Objective-C Bridging Header** to the path of your bridging header file.
- Clean and build your project.

That's all folks!

Comment: Haha loved how you closed the answer: "That's all folks!" ahah. Anyway that trick worked perfectly! Thanks man :)

Comment: No worries. I remember spending an hour trying to wrap my head around that problem!